# How to create a searchable select option form in laravel blade

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, forms

I'm attempting to build a city select option form with a searchable option. So far, I've built this, but the selected data isn't being saved, and my code still lacks the search feature.

```
{!! Form::select('custom_field1', array('Delhi', 'Goa'), '1', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select City']); !!}
```

Original Code

```xml
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('custom_field1', $contact_custom_field1 . ':') !!}
        {!! Form::text('custom_field1', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => $contact_custom_field1]); !!}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use `<input>`'s `list` attribute and `<datalist>` to achieve what you're trying to do with just html

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="custom_field1">{{ $contact_custom_field1 }}:</label>
        <input id="custom_field1" name="custom_field1" type="text" list="custom_field1_datalist" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $contact_custom_field1 }}">
        <datalist id="custom_field1_datalist">
            <option>Delhi</option>
            <option>Goa</option>
        </datalist>
        <span id="error" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This **will** allow any text input to be passed through, so you'll need a bit of additional validation.

```js
$('#your-form-id').on('submit', e => {
    $('#error').empty();
    let form = $(e.target);
    let validOptions = form.find('#custom_field1_datalist option').map((key, option) => option.value).toArray();
    let customField1Value = form.find('input[name=custom_field1]').eq(0).val();

    // check if custom_field_1's value is in the datalist. If it's not, it's an invalid choice
    if ( !(validOptions.indexOf(customField1Value) > -1) ) {
        // show error
        $('#error').text('Invalid Choice');
        // prevent form submission (you should still validate in the backend)
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

---

Alternativaly, since you've tagged this question with the JQuery tag, you could use a library like [`select2`](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage) and let it do that for you.

You only need to place this in your `<head>` tag

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Add the `select2` class to your select.

```xml
<select name="custom_field1" class="form-control select2" placeholder="Select City" required>
    <option>Delhi</option>
    <option>Goa</option>
</select>
```

And then, in your javascript, add this in your `$(document.ready(...)` block.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select2').select2();
});
```

Comment: You are awesome, it worked, I am currently on 11 points and I can up the answer, sorry for that

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Don't worry about that. I think you can still accept the answer.